# How can I select several scattered columns in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with 35 columns, and I want to create a new DataFrame with 6 of those columns. The relevant columns are distributed at various places throughout the DataFrame. What's the most Pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have a `dataframe` with multiple columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3], 'col2':[4,5,6],'col3':[7,8,9],
           'col4':[1,2,3],'col5':[1,2,3],'col6':[1,2,3],
           'col7':[1,2,3],'col8':[1,2,3],'col9':[1,2,3],
           'col91':[1,2,3]})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8  col9  col91
0     1     4     7     1     1     1     1     1     1      1
1     2     5     8     2     2     2     2     2     2      2
2     3     6     9     3     3     3     3     3     3      3
```

Now to create new `dataframe` with selected columns, you can just pass the list of names of the columns to selected `['col1', 'col2', 'col5']`:

```
tmp_df = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col5']]
print(tmp_df)
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col5
0     1     4     1
1     2     5     2
2     3     6     3
```

For some more you can refer to [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44622241/5916727)

Comment: This is great! Would it also be possible to do this with the index numbers of the columns?

Comment: @user1917407 Sure, you can use `tmp_df = df[[0,1,4]]` which would result same as `tmp_df = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col5']]` in this case.

Comment: @user1917407 np! I am happy I could help. `Happy Coding`.